# How do I create an element which will allow the height to be detected by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to create an element (a div) on my webpage, but not use `position:absolute;`

The div will need to be 100% of the page, but I need to be able to grab the actual height in pixels via JavaScript.

How do I style this with CSS to allow this JavaScript functionality? Please, no JQuery

Comment: You can get the height of any element using JS, no matter how it's styled with CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See comments inline:

```js
// Create a <div> dynamically
var div = document.createElement("div");

// Attach CSS class to div
div.setAttribute("class", "height100");

// Add to the document
document.body.append(div);

// Get the actual height of the element:
console.log("The height of the div is: " + window.getComputedStyle(div).height);
```

```css
.height100 { height: 100vh; }
```

Comment: indeed it does @ScottMarcus. I'm aware of getBoundingClientRect (which I didn't state) and was more interested in the CSS to achieve this. +1, testing now